# how to insert space separated input into an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

I've read other things on stack on the subject but all of it was too specific for me to understand. Couldn't find helpful info on geeks for geeks.

Basically all I have to do is store a space-separated string of integers into an array.

So a string like

"10 5 15 7 12 8"

stored as individual elements. I do not know how large the array will be, and we haven't covered vectors yet so I'm not familiar with it at all.

I'd offer my code but I basically don't have any. I have no idea how to do this. All I need to do is get input stored as an array so I can pass that input onto a function, but I've spent two hours trying to figure out just how to store that input in the first place. It's not even what my assignment is over.

Please help, you'll make my night. Thank you.

Comment: You could use a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse the string into separate numbers, and add them to a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). And you can do it all with only two statements if you use [`std::istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator).